# Zend_Navigation add dynamically parameter after question mark

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-config

I'm using Zend_Navigation' reading fron xml.
I want to add to the menu created from it an additional parameter (got it from the request for the first page).

e.g
if the first page is mysite.com/pages/page1?Id=42
then
clicking on the menu would add the **"?Id=42"** to each link.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is by extending the `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url` class, and adding the query string to the `parent::url()` result. Than, you need to inject your url helper into the mvc page, by calling `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc::setUrlHelper($yourUrlHelper)`.

Example of a query string supported url helper:

```
class My_Helper_Url extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url
{
    public function url($urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)
    {
        $queryString = $this->getRequest()->getServer('QUERY_STRING');

        return parent::url($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode) . 
            ($queryString ? '?' . $queryString : '');
    }
}
```